# How to set copy to C-c in Emacs?

Tags: key-bindings, copy-paste

I have tried using Cua mode (via adding `(cua-mode t)` to my `~/.emacs` file) but it doesn't seem to set the copy keybinding to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>. See for example this screenshot showing my Edit menu:

[image]

I have tried adding this line to my `~/.emacs` file:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c") 'kill-ring-save)
```

but still `C-c` doesn't copy selected text in an Emacs buffer (and the Edit menu looks the same as in the above screenshot). If you are wondering whether some other line in my `~/.emacs` file is overriding this one, feel free to see for yourself. [Here](https://github.com/fusion809/emacs/blob/9848e217391a0d2abf92d59da37d8a58f1179267/.emacs) is my `~/.emacs` file.

Comment: Try `C-h k C-c` to see what `C-c` is bound to.

Comment: [Here](http://i.imgur.com/RlafDjZ.png) is a screenshot showing what it does. It doesn't seem to recognize it as a keybinding by itself.

Comment: Yes, because global-set-key always set keys with the prefix C-x. Try `C-h k C-x C-c`

Comment: It doesn't seem to recognize that sequence of keybindings either, after C-x it just sees C-c (and forgets preceding key strokes). [Here](http://i.imgur.com/Uk6j6Mc.png) is my screenshot.

Comment: Looks like C-x is bound correctly as you wish? (Cut text)

Comment: Sure does, makes me quite pleased. I opened `~/.emacs` after seeing that and tried out C-x and it cut the text fine. So I'll go close that question. This one still stands.

Comment: @xuhdev You seem to have thought this question was closed, no it's the other question about cut and C-x. This question is about copy and C-c! Sorry if you're just thinking of a solution or stuck on it, just making sure you're not mistaken in thinking this question had been answered.

Comment: You seem to have multiple questions that all ask about how to get CUA mode key bindings to work. Please consider deleting all but one. There is no need for a question about `C-c`, another question about `C-x`, another about `C-a`, another about `C-z`, another about...

Comment: Did you check that _Use CUA Keys_ is enabled under _Options_ menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have tried using Cua mode (via adding `(cua-mode t)` to my
>   `~/.emacs` file) but it doesn't seem to set the copy keybinding to
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>.

It does, but only when you highlight text, see [CUA Bindings](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/CUA-Bindings.html) <kbd><kbd>f1</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>m</kbd>cua<kbd>RET</kbd></kbd>

> The command M-x cua-mode sets up key bindings that are compatible with
>   the Common User Access (CUA) system used in many other applications.
>
> When CUA mode is enabled, the keys C-x, C-c, C-v, and C-z invoke
>   commands that cut (kill), copy, paste (yank), and undo respectively.
>   The C-x and C-c keys perform cut and copy only if the region is
>   active. Otherwise, they still act as prefix keys, so that standard
>   Emacs commands like C-x C-c still work. Note that this means the
>   variable mark-even-if-inactive has no effect for C-x and C-c (see
>   Using Region).

For technical reasons, <kbd><kbd>f1</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd></kbd> when text is highlighted says `C-c runs the command cua--prefix-override-handler` rather than `kill-ring-save` or `cua-copy-region`, and similarly the menu won't reflect the CUA bindings.